# How to make repeater item works outside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I've started to experiment a little bit with AngularJS.
Now I think I have a newbie problem with ng-class.
I'm trying to change the color of an icon of awesome font.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<i ng-class="{'test': item.active}" class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
```

I have a checkbox and have a binding via ng-model to the parameter

```
<div class="checkboxes">
  <form>
    <span ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.active"> {{item.name}}<br>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

When I click the checkbox, the scope is like:

```
[{"category":"category1","name":"Item1","active":true}]
```

But the class of the i-element is only "fa fa-bullhorn".

The color is at the start black, the css class test looks like

```
.test{
color: red;
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: `item` is not available inside the scope where your `i` element is declared. It seems `items` is the property that's available on your scope, did you want to change the class if any `items` have an `active` property?

Comment: try invert `ng-class` with `class` like `<i class="fa fa-bullhorn" ng-class="{'test': item.active}"></i>`

Comment: I wan't to have several Icons in a div above the checkboxes. Every Icon will have it's own checkbox. If a checkbox is clicked (avtive), the color should change.

invert doesn't work, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<i ng-class="{'test': item.active}" class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
```

**item.active** should be inside **repeater** like this

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.active"> {{item.name}} {{item.active}}
      <i ng-class="{'test': item.active}" class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i><br>
</span>
```

Look the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/RcposHlL8uSLZs39IvyK

Comment: The demo looks good, but I want to have something different:
I want to have several icons of Font awesome "above" the checkboxes, not inline. 
Thats why there is another div around checkboxes.

How can I change the color of the icons when they aren't inline but above?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I created a plunker example which is the example I have:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4IA45v4pzyzCu7DAclkK

Comment: Each repeater item has own scope which cannot communicate with outside. You need a separate repeater. Look at this [http://plnkr.co/edit/0uPsMbDgK2KhUmKWgpje](http://plnkr.co/edit/0uPsMbDgK2KhUmKWgpje)

Comment: Many thanks, yout plnkr-example is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Does that icon exist within `ng-repeat="item in items"`? If not, "item" does not exist in the the icon's context.